# How to make all the fields visible in the new Task form of Tasks List in SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, .net, sharepoint-2013

I have created a Tasks List in SharePoint. When I try to add a new Task, it opens a form with few visible fields like ***TaskName, StartDate, DueDate, Description, AssignedTo***. When I click on *'ShowMore'*, then it is showing all the remaining fields like ***%complete, TaskStatus, Priority, Comments, ExpectedDueDate.***

**Issue:** I want all the fields to be visible from the start without clicking on ***'ShowMore'***, because some people might get confused with this option and may skip filling these fields. Can someone please kindly suggest how to achieve this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: hi, just change few order it will display it. I faced same problem, i just change order in view

Comment: Thank you Richa for your quick response..from your answer I was able to get the invisible fields in a list view :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such setting that allows to configure fields visibility in tasks form AFIK.
But task form could be customized in order to display all the fields as demonstrated below.

Since it is a SharePoint 2013 environment, the following approach is suggested:

- Create rendering template to display all the fields in  New & Edit forms
- Update Task web part in New & Edit forms pages

### Template file

The following example demonstrates how to display all the fields of Task form:

```
(function () {


    function preTaskFormRenderer(renderCtx) {
       rlfiShowMore();
    }


    function registerRenderer()
    {
      var ctxForm = {};
      ctxForm.Templates = {};
      ctxForm.OnPreRender = preTaskFormRenderer;

      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

### How to apply changes

1. Upload the specified script (lets name it `TaskForm.js`) into SharePoint `Site Assets` library
2. Open New Form page in edit mode and go to Tasks web part properties
3. Specify `JS Link` property located under `Miscellaneous` group: `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/TaskForm.js` (see pic. 1)
4. Save changes and repeat steps 2-4 for Edit form

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Vadim for your quick response and elaborate explanation. I was able to achieve my desired functionality using your approach...:)

Comment: Bhargav, glad this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer other methods to the JavaScript workaround to really solve the problem:
1. You can change the list form assigned to the local Task content type, for example via PowerShell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YourSharePointSite 
$list = $web.Lists["Tasks"] 
$ct = $list.ContentTypes[0] 
$ct.DisplayFormTemplateName = "ListForm" 
$ct.NewFormTemplateName = "ListForm" 
$ct.EditFormTemplateName = "ListForm" 
$ct.Update()
```

2. You can set the list form assigned to the ListFormWebPart via SharePoint Designer
3. Create your own control template and add the ShowExpanded="true" attribute to the TaskListFieldIterator control
4. Pass the Expanded=1 in the request query string like NewForm.aspx?Expanded=1
5. Change the default column order of the local Task content type

All of these have the effect of displaying all the fields without the "Show More" button. You can read more about these methods here:
http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2014/11/01/no-more-show-more-in-tasks-lists/